# react type error when fetching new array state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to convert this code

```
// this.setState({
//     description:'',   // resets title after upload
//     images: [
//       {
//         id: newImage[0].id,
//         user:{
//             username: newImage[0].user.username
//         },
//         // comments:{
//         //   comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
//         // },
//         image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
//         img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
//         created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
//         updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
//       },
//       ...this.state.images
//     ]
//   })
```

to a redux reducer, here was my attempt

**Snippet Reducer**

```
case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
const newState = {...state}
const myImages = newState.images // old images

const newImage = action.newImage
console.log(newImage); // gets the new uploaded image. 
return {
    images:[
        ...myImages,
        {
            id: newImage[0].id,
            user:{
                username: newImage[0].user.username
            },
            // comments:{
            //   comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
            // },
            image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
            img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
            created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
            updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
        }

    ]

}
```

As of right now, images[] are being mapped in the dashboard component, and it fetches images from redux reducer  `case GET_IMAGES:`. The issue comes when uploading an image. I get the error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

and on refresh, the new uploaded images shows within the map iteration.

My guess is that the *old images* are contained in an array, and the *new images* is in an array within an object i guess i don't know.

**old images data structure (edited for privacy)**

```
[
  {
    "id": 217,
    "image_title": "ddddddf",
    "img_url": "http:/************579/uploads/lshndpj***g",
    "created_at": "2019-06-16T17:03:00.605Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-16T17:03:00.605Z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "googleId": null,
      "username": "E****",
      "password": *****$12$16UTTfIH6gXhnRMnBHFGHuHiI***EAGF3GCjO62",
      "email": "e****",
      "created_at": "2019-06-05T04:50:20.133Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-06-05T04:50:20.133Z"
    },
    "comments": []
  },
```

**New uploaded Image data structure(edited for privacy)**

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 218,
    "image_title": "owl",
    "img_url": "http:/*********0705077/uploads******",
    "created_at": "2019-06-16T17:11:19.066Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-16T17:11:19.066Z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "googleId": null,
      "username": "BOB",
      "password": "$2b$12******"
      "created_at": "2019-06-05T04:50:20.133Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-06-05T04:50:20.133Z"
    },
    "comments": []
  },
```

Maybe there is a discrepancy with the data structure which is why it gives me the type error when looping through the array.

**full code**

*actions*

```
export const uploadImage = data =>  {
   return (dispatch) => {
    Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
        const newImage = {...response.data}
        console.log(newImage);
        dispatch({type:UPLOAD_IMAGE, newImage})    
   } 

}


// get images
export const getImages = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
                const data = response.data;
                dispatch({ 
                    type: GET_IMAGES,
                    data
                })
            });
    }
}
```

*reducer*

```
import { GET_IMAGES, POST_COMMENT, DELETE_IMAGE, UPLOAD_IMAGE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    images:[],

}

export default  (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_IMAGES:
            console.log(action.data);
            return{
                ...state,
                images:action.data
            }
        case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
            const newState = {...state}
            const myImages = newState.images // old images

            const newImage = action.newImage
            console.log(newImage); // gets the new uploaded image. 
            return {
                images:[
                    ...myImages,
                    {
                        id: newImage[0].id,
                        user:{
                            username: newImage[0].user.username
                        },
                        // comments:{
                        //   comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                        // },
                        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                        updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
                    }

                ]

            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

*Dashboard.js*

```
const { image} = this.props

{image.images.length > 0 ? (
        image.images.map( (img, i) => (   
            <div key={i}>
                <ImageContainer img={img} deleteImg={() => this.deleteImg(img.id)}/>
            </div>      
        ))
    ) : (
    <div>
        <Grid item md={8}>
            <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
        </Grid>
    </div>
)}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   image: state.image
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   getImages: () => dispatch(getImages()),
   deleteImage : (id) => dispatch(deleteImage (id)),
   uploadImage: (data) => dispatch(uploadImage(data))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)
```

Comment: There is issue in your reducer in case of GET_IMAGE you're returning an object with key images so it is accessible in component by image.images but in case of UPLOAD_IMAGE you're returning an object with likes key only ( no images key) so after uploading image, image.images is undefined in component

Comment: i made a big mistake. likes is supposed to be images. oops. let me edit

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you return from a reducer replaces the previous redux state. So in your case, your initial state was something similar to:

```
{
  images: [],
  ...
}
```

But in `UPLOAD_IMAGE` action, your are returning an object with only `likes` property:

```
{
  likes: ...
}
```

So the previous state gets replaced by this and your `state.image.images` returns `undefined`. To solve this use the spread pattern, assign previous state into the new state first, then assign `likes` data:

```
{
  ...previousState,
  likes: ...
}
```

Comment: made a big mistake, likes was supposed to be images. i edited the original code.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in comment that there is issue in your reducer, you can fix it by

```
case UPDATE_IMAGE: 
return {
    images: [ ...state.images, action.newImage[0]]
}
```

Comment: i tried this, and it doesn't post the new image immediately, their is no more type error, but i have to refresh to see the new image. I'm still tinkering with this. thanks though.

Comment: found a solution

Answer (score 0):

with the help from @mezba and @Abhay Sehgal

I found a working solution, thanks folks

```
 case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
            const newState = {...state}
            const myImages = newState.images // old images

            const newImage = action.newImage
            console.log(newImage[0]); // gets the new uploaded image. 
            return {
                images:[

                    {
                        id: newImage[0].id,
                        user:{
                            username: newImage[0].user.username
                        },
                        // comments:{
                        //   comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                        // },
                        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                        updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
                    },
                    myImages[0]

                ]

            }
```